# Install certificates https in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, single-sign-on

Our organization is evaluating the use of Salesforce1. In order to be able to use it is a requirement that we can implement SSO via SAML.

To further assess the feasibility of implementing it our IT teams ask us the following: 
   - Our IDPs use a HTTPS certificate signed by our own entity CA (private if I'm not mistaken) . Is it a problem? 
   - Is it possible to install an HTTPS certificate in Salesforce1 that recognizes our IDP?

We have salesforce instance with Single Sign-on configured via SAML for connection between IDP and salesforce
This IDP cannot be used with salesforce URL due to some network issues but when exposed to  internet the devices will be able to reach to. So we need know if we will be able to connect via SAML and expose new IDP to the internet so these devices with smartphones will be able to reach it plus the IT team is saying that the HTTPS connection that is established for these IDP will discard the certificate build by our own IT team, so we want to know if this is necessary to install this certificate at the app side or may be its not necessary to insatll the certificate at the app side.

Comment: Are you asking whether Salesforce has to be able reach your identity provider? If so - not really. Many identity providers are actually localhost Microsoft Active Directory servers. I am sure using self-signed certificate will be fine as long as you install in your host device (iOS/Android). Essentially this is how very popular corporate traffic monitors like WebMarshal (or some recent Dell and Lenovo laptops) MITM attack their users :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates

The list of accepted CA is above .If you are using private CA you may raise case with support to see if they support.I feel it has to be only from above list.